# Pushing index of response array in an array using map in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

How to store the indices of a response array object in an array or object using map in react?

```
data:
 mat:
  opts: 
   0: {text: "1"}
   1: {text: "2"}
   2: {text: "3"}
   3: {text: "4"}
   4: {text: "5"}
   5: {text: "6"}
   6: {text: "7"}
   7: {text: "8"}
   8: {text: "9"}
   9: {text: "10"}
```

Array length is fixed i.e, 10.

Comment: Can you please show how you're planning on using this information? There's likely another way of getting this information than what you've proposed.

Comment: I just need the index 0 to 9 stored in an array

Answer (score 0):

I have found it....

```
const element = props.data.mat.opts.map((el, i) => console.log(i));
```

It will return

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

We can store it in an array..

```
let arr = [];
const element = props.data.mat.opts.map((el, i) => arr.push(i));
```